# Eclipse Nios2 returning an error :Invalid arguments for memcpy

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using eclipse nios2 for running out an embedded application.

I have a memcpy line

```
memcpy (fastmessagedata-> var1 , _out.voltgae , sizeof(float));
```

Both the var1 and voltage are float variables.

But the eclipse returns an error:

```
Invalid arguments :Candidates are void* memcpy(void* , const void*, unsigned long int)
```

Please Help

Comment: Why would you want to use `memcpy()` instead of a simple assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as you say, the variables are `float`, you need to provide their addresses to `memcpy` as follows

```
memcpy (&fastmessagedata->var1 , &_out.voltgae , sizeof(float));
```

your compilation error is telling you that you must provide pointer arguments. Using `memcpy` in this way is pretty pointless though since

```
fastmessagedata->var1  = _out.voltgae;
```

will achieve the same result.